# Alter 'admin/content' – hide content types

Tags: drupal-7

i have a role that only can add/edit nodes of a certain content type. My problem is the list of contents in the backend ('admin/content/node'), where users with this role see nodes of any type.

Is there a way to exclude all other nodes by default? No, the filter is not enough…

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and [Admin Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) you can replace admin/content, admin/people and admin/comments with views.

This gives you the possibility to set criteria for the page and hide some content types.

Comment: Thanks! That´s the flexibility i need.